# How to know that Snapshot Listener is finished | firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code that fetch data from specific sub-collection:

```
 db.collection("groups").document(id.get(i)).collection("members")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                id.add(document.getId());
                                Log.e(Tag, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());

                                if (task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                                    Log.d(Tag, "onSuccess: LIST EMPTY");
                                    return;
                                } else {
                                    // Convert the whole Query Snapshot to a list
                                    // of objects directly! No need to fetch each
                                    // document.
                                    Log.e(Tag, task.getResult() + "");
                                    typeAll = task.getResult().toObjects(GroupMembers.class);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.e(Tag, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
```

But I need to call a method after fetching all the data by snapshots. How to achieve that? what should I test?

Answer (score 4):

> How to know that Snapshot Listener is finished?

The Snapshot Listener is always listening for changes, unless you are [removing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699032/how-to-set-addsnapshotlistener-and-remove-in-populateviewholder-in-recyclerview/48702579#48702579).

If you are looking to know when the data is completed loading from the database, note that you cannot know when all the `members` are completed downloaded becase `Cloud Fireatore` is a **realtime database** and getting data might never complete. That's why is named a realtime database because in any momemnt the data under the `members` collection can be changed, properties can be added or deleted.

You can use a `CompletionListener` only when you **write** or **update** data and you'll be notified when the operation has been acknowledged by Firebase servers but you cannot use this interface when reading data.

Comment: thanks a lot, good explaining.
what I need is recalled my adapter after fetching new data,
I used a handler to wait for 5 secondes but that is not the right way to do it

Comment: It seems that this is another question but in my opinion you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method in order to refresh the adapter or to create a new instance if needed.

Comment: Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Ok, give it a try and keep me posted.

Answer (score 0):

Call your method to process the object list after you retrieve it:

```
                           if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                    id.add(document.getId());
                                    Log.e(Tag, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());

                                    if (task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                                        Log.d(Tag, "onSuccess: LIST EMPTY");
                                        return;
                                    } else {
                                        // Convert the whole Query Snapshot to a list
                                        // of objects directly! No need to fetch each
                                        // document.
                                        Log.e(Tag, task.getResult() + "");
                                        typeAll = task.getResult().toObjects(GroupMembers.class);

                                        // do something with typeall here

                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.e(Tag, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                            }
```