# How to safely remove firestore listeners before user clicks signout?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 fragment tabs in the main activity (tab1 and tab2). and both tabs has the snapshot listener attached to them. I have one other activity that also includes snapshot listener (act1). and the signout button is on tab2.

Tab1-----

```
private RecyclerView recyclerViewChatsView;

private ChatsAdapter usersRecyclerAdapter;
private ArrayList<UsersClass> mUsers;

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;

private ArrayList<String> usersList;

ListenerRegistration usersListenerRegistration;
ListenerRegistration chatsListenerRegistration;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

    recyclerViewChatsView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewChatsView);
    recyclerViewChatsView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewChatsView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));



    return view;
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    usersList = new ArrayList<>();
    mUsers = new ArrayList<>();

    chatsListenerRegistration = firebaseFirestore.collection("chats")
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots,
                                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                        usersList.clear();


                        for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {


                            if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                                ChatsClass chatsClass = doc.getDocument().toObject(ChatsClass.class);

                                if (chatsClass.getChat_sender().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                                    usersList.add(chatsClass.getChat_receiver());
                                }
                                if (chatsClass.getChat_receiver().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                                    usersList.add(chatsClass.getChat_sender());
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }
                });


            mUsers.clear();
            usersListenerRegistration = firebaseFirestore.collection("users")
                    .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots,
                                            @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                            for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                                if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                                    UsersClass usersClass = doc.getDocument().toObject(UsersClass.class);


                                    if (usersList.contains(usersClass.getUser_uid())) {

                                        mUsers.add(usersClass);

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                            usersRecyclerAdapter = new ChatsAdapter(mUsers, getActivity());
                            recyclerViewChatsView.setAdapter(usersRecyclerAdapter);
                        }
                    });


            authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    if (user != null) {
                        // User is signed in
                    } else {
                        // User is signed out
                        usersListenerRegistration.remove();
                        chatsListenerRegistration.remove();
                    }
                }
            };

            firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);

}
```

Tab 2 -------------------------

```
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;

private TextView textViewUserName;
private TextView textViewUserGender;
private TextView textViewUserAge;
private TextView textViewUserEmail;

private Button btnAccount;
private Button btnUserSignOut;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String currentUser = firebaseUser.getUid();
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    textViewUserEmail = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserEmail);
    textViewUserName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserName);
    textViewUserGender = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserGender);
    textViewUserAge = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserAge);

    btnAccount = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnAccount);
    btnUserSignOut = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnUserSignOut);


    firebaseFirestore.collection("users")
            .document(currentUser)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();

                        String user_email = documentSnapshot.getString("user_email");
                        String user_name = documentSnapshot.getString("user_name");
                        String user_gender = documentSnapshot.getString("user_gender");
                        String user_age = documentSnapshot.getString("user_age");


                        textViewUserEmail.setText(user_email);
                        textViewUserName.setText(user_name);
                        textViewUserGender.setText(user_gender);
                        textViewUserAge.setText(user_age);

                    }
                }
            });

    btnAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String stringUserEmail = textViewUserEmail.getText().toString();
            String stringUserName = textViewUserName.getText().toString();
            String stringUserGender = textViewUserGender.getText().toString();
            String stringUserAge = textViewUserAge.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccountActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("intentUserEmail", stringUserEmail);
            intent.putExtra("intentUserName", stringUserName);
            intent.putExtra("intentUserGender", stringUserGender);
            intent.putExtra("intentUserAge", stringUserAge);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnUserSignOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            firebaseAuth.signOut();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

and act1------------------

```
TextView usersProfileUserName;
TextView usersProfileUserGender;
TextView usersProfileUserAge;

String usersProfileUserUid;

Button buttonProfileChat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_users_profile);

    buttonProfileChat = findViewById(R.id.btnUsersProfileChat);

    usersProfileUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUsersProfileUserName);
    usersProfileUserGender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUsersProfileUserGender);
    usersProfileUserAge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUsersProfileUserAge);

    usersProfileUserName.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("user_name"));
    usersProfileUserGender.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("user_gender"));
    usersProfileUserAge.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("user_age"));
    usersProfileUserUid = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_uid");

    buttonProfileChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(UsersProfileActivity.this,MessageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("user_uid", usersProfileUserUid);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

now, when user moves across tabs fragments (tab1 to tab 2) and signout, its fine but when the user clicks on the tab1, and goes to act1 and than return back to tab1 and goes to tab2 to signout, the app crashes.

and the error is get is-----

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.getDocumentChanges()' on a null object reference
at com.sunny.chatapp.ChatsFragment$2.onEvent(ChatsFragment.java:98)
at com.sunny.chatapp.ChatsFragment$2.onEvent(ChatsFragment.java:90)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzg.onEvent(Unknown Source:1792)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzh.zza(SourceFile:28)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzi.run(Unknown Source:6)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6635)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

I have attached FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener and ListenerRegistration too on all the three pages but still the crash happesn.

I am sure something is wrong somewhere. have a look at it.
Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question with the details about the crash.  Without seeing that, people are less likely to read through all your code to look for a problem.

Comment: Hi! Thank you. I updated it.

Comment: You are assuming that `queryDocumentSnapshots` is not null.  Apparently it is null.  You should check for null and error in the onEvent callback.

Comment: Wow! thats a very good suggestion. I will check and reply if it works.Thanks!

Comment: I checked before the for loop with this statement, if(queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges() != null) and it didnt worked. could you explain where should I check it?

Comment: I'm saying that `queryDocumentSnapshots` is null.  You can't call a method on a null object.

Comment: You can also check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699032/how-to-set-addsnapshotlistener-and-remove-in-populateviewholder-in-recyclerview/)** out.

Comment: Hi Alex! Thank you very much for the link. it perfectly solved my problem and now everything is working fine.