# How to stop snapshot listener which was inside the RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just having a certain problem about the Firestore snapshot listener. I am new on using it and I had read that you have to stop the snapshot listener everytime you move to another activity. I tried:

```
db.collection("Mydata").document(userID).addSnapshotListener(itemView.getContext(), new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    }
                })
```

But it has an error because of the `itemView.getContext()`.

My questions are:

- Is it okay if I don't include the `Activity` in and leave the snapshotlistener like that?
- If not, Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it okay if I don't include the Activity in and leave the snapshotlistener like that?

No, it is not! When you are calling `addSnapshotListener` for [listening to realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection), it means that you attach a listener that gets called for every change that takes place in your database. So this is happening also when your app is closed, that's why it's mandatory to [detach the listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) before the activity gets destroyed.

> If not, Is there any way to solve this?

Yes, there is. Please see my answer from the following post:

- [How to set addSnapshotListener and remove in populateViewHolder in RecyclerView Item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699032/how-to-set-addsnapshotlistener-and-remove-in-populateviewholder-in-recyclerview/)

> If in your app you don't need to get the data in realtime, then you can simply use a [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) call directly on the reference, which just reads the document only once. Since it only reads once, there is no listener to be removed.