# Is removeEventListener() is not a part of Firebase Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I am getting the error in my `onPause()` method saying:

`Cannot resolve method 'removeEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)'`

I guess I might have done some mistakes while trying to convert [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/E1qm09JWUdI) (where the app displays whether the receiver of the message has seen the message or not) from Firebase Realtime Database to Firebase Firestore.

Declaration of the `ValueEventListener` takes place before the onCreate() method

```
ValueEventListener seenListener;
```

seenMessage() method

```
private void seenMessage(final String recipientId){
        final CollectionReference reference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("chats");
        seenListener = (ValueEventListener) reference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if(documentSnapshots!=null){
                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots : documentSnapshots){
                        Chat chat = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObject(Chat.class);
                        if (chat.getReceiver().equals(userId) && chat.getSender().equals(recipientId)){
                            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("isseen", true);
                            reference.add(hashMap);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

onPause() method

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("chats").removeEventListener(seenListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is removeEventListener() is not a part of Firebase Firestore?

No, it's not. The following line of code:

```
reference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {/* ... */}
```

Return a [ListenerRegistration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/ListenerRegistration) object and there is no way in Java in which you can cast this type of object to a [ValueEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener) object. The `ValueEventListener` is a part of Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore is a totally different product.

As I see in your code, you are using Cloud Firestore. If you want to remove the listener, please see my answer from the following post:

- [How to set addSnapshotListener and remove in populateViewHolder in RecyclerView Item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699032/how-to-set-addsnapshotlistener-and-remove-in-populateviewholder-in-recyclerview/)

Comment: Hi Athanasius! Is there everything alright? Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `eventListener` inside a method:

```
private void seenMessage(final String recipientId){
    EventListener<DocumentSnapshot> eventListener = new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() { ... }
    ...
}
```

This means that the `eventListner` variable will only be visible to other code **inside** that method.  You're trying to access it `eventListener` **outside** of that method, which java does not allow.  This is called "variable scoping".  `eventListener` is "scoped" to the method `seenMethod`, which is the only place it can be referenced.

You can instead declare and assign `eventListener` outside of the method as a member variable of the class.  Then, you can use it in any method, just like `listenerRegistration`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can detach an event listener in firestore

```
  void detachListener() {
   
      Query query = db.collection("cities");
      ListenerRegistration registration = query.addSnapshotListener(
        new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
           @Override
           public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                          @Nullable FirestoreException e) {

            } 
        });
      // ...
      // Stop listening to changes
      registration.remove();
  }
```