# Firestore reads and cache

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to understand more about the reading from the server and reading from the cache and what is billable.

In this answer to a similar question Alex states:

> However, if you perform a query, "again and again", as long as it's the same query and nothing has changed on the server, then you will not be charged with any read operations. This is happening because the second time you perform the query, the results are coming from the cache.

How do we know that the second query (identical to the first) is coming from the cache when the `snapshot.metadata.isFromCache` field is still `false`? Another from Alex states similar thoughts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617814/questions-about-firestore-cache-and-reads-charge).

According to Doug in comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971764/am-i-charged-in-firestore-again-for-document-reads-if-i-open-the-app-second-day) he states:

> The bottom line is this: unless you are offline or querying the cache explicitly, you are charged for all results that come from the server.

These seem to be opposing views. I understand I can explicitly query the cache, that's not in question. I'm just trying to understand if I run the same query 10 times and 10 documents are returned each time (similar to Alex's example/comment) will I be charged for 100 reads or 10? (assuming the network is available the whole time).

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote an article called:

> [How to drastically reduce the number of reads when no documents are changed in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e)

In which I have explained everything regarding Firestore billing. I have also added a workaround on how to reduce the number of reads when there are no documents changed in the database.

And to answer your questions:

> However, if you perform a query, "again and again", as long as it's the same query and nothing has changed on the server, then you will not be charged with any read operations.

This is happening as long as the (real-time) listener stays active.

Regarding the second answer, if you are listening for real-time changes and you perform a second query, within the 30 min limit, the results will always come from the cache. However, if you're only using a get() call, then each time you perform such an operation, you'll be billed as in the case of performing a brand new query.

When you are offline, and as long as you have the offline persistence enable, which is by default enabled in Firestore, you'll always read the data from the cache. Cache reads have **no** cost.

> if I run the same query 10 times and 10 documents are returned each time (similar to Alex's example/comment) will I be charged for 100 reads or 10?

If you're using a get() call, you'll be charged with 100 reads, but if you're listening for real-time updates and the listener isn't disconnected for 30 minutes, then you'll have to pay only 10 reads.

Comment: In all my reading I never realized some were about the real-time listener and others about .get() and that they are different, I appreciate the clarification. Also, I’m surprised I never came across your article. Thank you for your patience and your time in answering!

Comment: You're very welcome, xJeevesxx.

Comment: Read your article this is very good info. I had one question though. If I do an initial query to load from the cache or create the cache the way you describe in the article, for the UI if I use SnapshotListeners will the initial get from that listener pull from the cache or will it pull from the database and charge me? I understand I could use a get to setup the UI but I still need to react to changes.

Comment: @wshamp When you attach a listener for the first time, you'll get the data from the server. There is no way you ca n skip this step.

Comment: Your article is under a paywall. Maybe add an open alternative?

Comment: It says it lasts for 30 minutes, but will the listening be cut off after 30 minutes from the first reception? For example, if the user is still listening, will it be 2 hours and 3 hours and will the listening be held uninterrupted? Then there will be no cost, so every 29 minutes it comes and goes ^^;

Comment: @SwiftStarter If you don't disconnect the lister, meaning you'll keep it active for more than 30 minutes, then you'll only pay for what's new.

Comment: What about this? If I keep looking at the screen I'm subscribed to on the app, wouldn't it be 2 hours, 3 hours, and the listening be cut off?
Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: @SwiftStarter Asking a follow-up question should be typically a new post. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.