# How to remove OnCompleteListener on .get() method when fragment is destroyed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

My project uses Firestore as the database. I am having a fragment which when opened requests a document from Firestore in its onCreate method. I have attached an OnCompleteListener to the .get() method so that when the document fetch is complete, it updates UI.

The issue is that sometimes the user, after opening the fragment, quickly moves on to another fragment before the onCompleteListener is triggered. Or in some cases, the same fragment is called twice and while the first instance of the fragment is destroyed, its onCompleteListener is still alive and triggers after the first instance of the Fragment is destroyed. In both these scenarios, I get an exception

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ProfileFragment{4ee762 (a8f7ae01-23be-4d47-b695-68e273b992bf)} not attached to a context.
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:774)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:838)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:860)
       at com.desivideshi.productinfo.ProfileFragment$18.onComplete(ProfileFragment.java:903)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:4)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.tasks.zzb.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:6)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Here is my code snippet inside ProfileFragment's onCreate method

```
documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                            if (mContext != null){
                                if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null && task.getResult().getData() != null) {
                                        Map<String, Object> productsDoc = task.getResult().getData();
                                        productsList = (List<Map<String, String>>) productsDoc.get(getString(R.string.fs_f_products_list));
                                   
                                    if(productsList == null){
                                        productsList = new ArrayList<>();
                                    }
                                      mMyProfileData.setMyProductsList(productsList);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed to load products", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                createTabLayout(); 
                                profileTabLayout.selectTab(profileTabLayout.getTabAt(profileTabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()));
                                progressLayoutProfileTab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Is there a way to remove the callback to OnCompleteListener which I can place in the `onDestry()` or `onDetach()` method of the Fragment in order to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to remove OnCompleteListener on .get() method when fragment is destroyed?

There is no need to remove any listeners, because the `get()` method gets the data exactly once and that's the end of it. If you have been used `addSnapshotListener()`, you should have removed the listener [according to the life-cycle of your activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699032/how-to-set-addsnapshotlistener-and-remove-in-populateviewholder-in-recyclerview/). In your case, the `onComplete()` method will fire only when the data is completely loaded from the database. What you need to know is that the Cloud Firestore client runs all network operations in a background thread. So don't do things that related to a context in a background thread.

If you need a real-time listener, then use the `addSnapshotListener()` and stop listening for changes once your activity/fragment is stoped. Please also remember that `onDestroy` is not always called, so stop listening for changes in `onStop()`.

**Edit:**

Because you are using things that are related to a context inside the callback, you should query the database only is `isAdded()` method returns `true`.

Comment: I don't intend to use snapshot listener because I need the data only once. Even though the get() method gets data only once, there is a lag of a few hundred millis upto a couple of seconds for the data to fetch. I need to handle the case if the fragment gets destroyed within that short span of time.

Comment: In that case, be sure that the Fragment is indeed attached to the activity. To solve this, you should call `isAdded()` method inside your fragment and do your logic only if this method returns true.

Comment: Because you are using things that are related to a context inside the callback, you should query the database only is `isAdded()` return true.

Comment: If you could edit your answer to include the `isAdded()` suggestion, I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to make changes to views directly in your listener (which is not really a good idea, more on that later), then you use should an [activity-scoped listener](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#activity-scoped_listeners) on the `Task` object returned by `get()`, so that the listener won't trigger after the activity becomes stopped.

```
documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(activity, callback)
```

Note that you're passing the activity instance as the first argument, before the callback.

However, it would be better for modern Android applications to use [MVVM architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide), as recommended by Google throughout Android documentation, to abstract away the database code from the views by exposing only a LiveData, which is aware of the activity lifecycle and will not emit events to observers after the activity stops.  But that's entirely up to you.

Comment: I am aware that passing activity as first argument would solve problem in case of changing activities. But here I am changing the fragment only and not the activity. I didn't find any similar alternative to pass the fragment instead. As a workaround I am currently using Alex's advice to use the `isAdded()` check inside onCompleteListener. And I will definitely check out the recommended MVVM architecture suggested by you.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way I think could be use a `try catch` so when you get the exception, nothing happens, it's a controlated exception.

The best way of solve this problems is to use a MVVM pattern with LiveData. ViewModel is aware of the lifeCycle of the activity / fragment and when your fragment dies, you don't get any background notifications from calls you did when the fragment was alive.

Try this

```
documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                            try{
                            if (mContext != null){
                                if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null && task.getResult().getData() != null) {
                                        Map<String, Object> productsDoc = task.getResult().getData();
                                        productsList = (List<Map<String, String>>) productsDoc.get(getString(R.string.fs_f_products_list));
                                   
                                    if(productsList == null){
                                        productsList = new ArrayList<>();
                                    }
                                      mMyProfileData.setMyProductsList(productsList);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed to load products", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                createTabLayout(); 
                                profileTabLayout.selectTab(profileTabLayout.getTabAt(profileTabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()));
                                progressLayoutProfileTab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                          }catch(Exception e){
                            //Use the exception inside a log, let it blank or as you prefer
                          }
                        }
                    });
```