# How to make the listener keep attached, even after an error occurs in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#handle_listen_errors) says that `After an error, the listener will not receive any more events, and there is no need to detach your listener.` But I don't want that behavior. Instead, I want the listener to be attached there itself, as in the future, there is still a chance of the listener getting permission to read from there.

Suppose if the rules say that, reading is allowed only if `readField` is `true`. Even if the current value of `readField` is `false`, it has a possibility of becoming `true`, so I want the listener to keep listening till I manually remove it when there is no need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the docs say, if your query fails or if you have improper security rules, the listener will not receive any more events. Unfortunately, this behavior cannot be changed.

What you might try to implement, is to attach the listener again, if you get an error message. But this might not be the best solution because if you forget to add the proper rules, you'll end up adding the listener over and over again.

What you should do is attach and detach the listener according to your app's state. For instance, in Android you do something like this:

- [How to set addSnapshotListener and remove in populateViewHolder in RecyclerView Item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699032/how-to-set-addsnapshotlistener-and-remove-in-populateviewholder-in-recyclerview/)

Comment: [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/270470/241242), I have implemented a function which re attaches the listener according to corresponding events. Just check it once please.

Comment: Looks good at first glance. Does it work the way you want?

Comment: I certainly would do that. But, with no offense, you already have 103k points, hence what's the significance for an additional 10 points.

Comment: It's not about the points it's about the fact that you were helped.