# How i can delete firestore listener?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I set the listener if `isNeedToListen = true`, otherwise I remove it, but it still works and I have set listeners that contradict each other when I enter the same chat room from different accounts

```
override fun listenMessage(
    receiver_id: String,
    user_id: String,
    messages: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Message>>,
    onSuccess: (ArrayList<Message>) -> Unit,
    isNeedToListen:Boolean
) {
    var listenUserMessage: ListenerRegistration? =  null
    var listenReceiverMessage: ListenerRegistration? =  null
    if(isNeedToListen){
        listenUserMessage = database
            .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
            .document(user_id)
            .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
            .addSnapshotListener { value, error -> ...
            }

        listenReceiverMessage = database
            .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
            .document(receiver_id)
            .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
            .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->...
            }
    }else{
        if(listenUserMessage !=null){
            listenUserMessage.remove()
        }
        if(listenReceiverMessage !=null){
            listenReceiverMessage.remove()
        }
    }

}
```

**UPD**
`isNeedToListen` coming from

```
firebaseRepostory.listenMessage(receiver_id, user_id, messages, onSuccess,false)
```

this code is executed `onStop()`

```
firebaseRepostory.listenMessage(receiver_id, user_id, messages, onSuccess,true)
```

this code is executed `onStart()`

Comment: Where is `isNeedToListen` coming from? Can show us more context?

Comment: @AlexMamo I added the information

Comment: And why do you say it is still active? Besides that, have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699032/how-to-set-addsnapshotlistener-and-remove-in-populateviewholder-in-recyclerview/)?

Comment: @AlexMamo because it's still active, and yes I read that

Comment: @AlexMamo I am very stupid, I had to make my listeners global, I am very inconsiderate, thank you very much

Comment: From the above comment, I believe that your issue is solved. Can you post your answer as a solution? So that, it will be useful for others who are facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a global listener would solve this problem. For more information refer this [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699032/how-to-set-addsnapshotlistener-and-remove-in-populateviewholder-in-recyclerview/) shared by @AlexMamo.